# Sendmail unable to email to specific domain

Tags: email, sendmail, email-bounces, dmarc, e-mailrelay

I have a server running Sendmail and is able to email to all domains except my company's email (company1.com).  I have tested to sending to gmail and other email providers with no issues. Sendmail is configured to use a 3rd party SMTP relay service called MailJet.

When sending to company1.com the SMTP relay does not receive the emails and the error log for sendmail is as follows.

```
company1 sendmail[676194]: 396L7G6I676194: from= Voicemail@company1.com, size=90, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202310062107.396L7G6I676194@company1.com>, relay=root@localhost
company1 sendmail[676196]: 396L7GsW676196: <user1@company1.com>... User unknown
company1 sendmail[676194]: 396L7G6I676194: to=user1@company1.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30090, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
```

When sending an email to gmail this is the logs.

```
company1 sendmail[668643]: 396KrnqT668643: from= Voicemail@company1.com, size=95, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202310062053.396KrnqT668643@company1.com>, relay=root@localhost
company1 sendmail[668645]: 396KrnVI668645: from=<Voicemail@company1.com>, size=337, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202310062053.396KrnqT668643@company1.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=company1.com [127.0.0.1]
company1 sendmail[668643]: 396KrnqT668643: to=user1@gmail.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30095, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (396KrnVI668645 Message accepted for delivery)
company1 sendmail[668647]: STARTTLS=client, relay=[104.199.96.85]., version=TLSv1.3, verify=OK, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits=256/256
company1 sendmail[668647]: 396KrnVI668645: to=<user1@gmail.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=120337, relay=[104.199.96.85]. [104.199.96.85], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK queued as 319dec48-ebc6-4f7d-a470-2c54a4091ac2)
```

My domain had the following records for DMARC. I have since removed it and it still does not work.

```
v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; fo=1; pct=100; rua=agg@company1.com; ruf=fail@company1.com
```

I have followed steps where people mentioned to modify the /etc/mail/sendmail.mc and add these lines at the end:

```
define(`MAIL_HUB', `company1.com.')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `company1.com.')dnl
```

This still does not fix it.  As far as I can tell sendmail is trying to use itself as a relay when emailing company1.com instead of going through the 3rd party smtp relay server (Mailjet). How can I fix this and get it to work?

Comment: **stat=User unknown** - it seems that the recipient is unknown to the destination server.

Comment: The user is unknown because the server running sendmail doesn't have any mailboxes/users.  It is an asterisk box that needs to send all voicemails to my 3rd party SMTP relay service however it keeps trying to relay to itself.

Comment: This appears to relate to incoming email - so why are you telling about a mail relay? Does mailjet also provide the public MX? Why did you try to tell the mail server it was its own relay? What has DMARC got to do with your mailboxes? The ONLY significant (and relevant) information in this post is `dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown` and you've not addressed this at all.

Comment: The mail server that the mailboxes are on is Office 365.  All emails to it works except coming from the server running sendmail because sendmail is trying to look for the mailboxes locally.  tsc_chazz perfectly described what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the server hostname was set to company1.com which was causing sendmail to force relay to itself.  Changing the hostname to server.company1.com fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default, sendmail running on a system in the domain `company1.com` will assume that it is the email server for that domain and will forward mail destined for that domain to itself, as you have discovered. I believe the feature you want is the mailertable; enable that in your sendmail configuration, then include an entry in `/etc/mail/mailertable` of the form

```
.company1.com:  smtp:mx.mailjet.com
```

where what follows the "smtp" is one of the mailers for your forwarding service. More detail here: [https://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/mailertables.html](https://www.sendmail.org/%7Eca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/mailertables.html)

Edit: because Sendmail's features require a backtick to open the quote, I can't show the feature syntax in a comment. Enabling mailertable in the M4 file is done with

```
FEATURE(`mailertable')dnl
```

Once you've created the mailertable you also have to turn it into a form that Sendmail can use with something like

```
makemap hash /etc/mail/mailertable < /etc/mail/mailertable
```

Comment: I modified /etc/mail/mailertable and added the following

.company1.com:  smtp:in-v3.mailjet.com

It still did not work after restarting sendmail.

I even tested

.company1.com: esmtp:mx.mailjet.com

Comment: You also have to enable mailertable in your sendmail configuration. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes the mailertable has been enabled and I've created the mailertable.

Comment: It looks like, in this case, it won't work because Mailjet wants username and password for SMTP authentication, before it will allow relay, and Sendmail does not seem to support that in a forwarder - or if it does, I'm unsure how to establish that. You mentioned that your company mailboxes are on Office 365; can you instead direct these mails direct to your company mailboxes there?